# Java 8 - Lambda Expression Convert List<String> to List<DTO>

Tags: java, arrays, regex, java-8, java-stream

I have a List like these. Want to perform some filteration and conversion of `List` of `String` to `List` of `DTO`:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] te = {"a","B_1","c","d","e"};      
        String[] con = {"a","b","ca"};

        List<String> S  = Arrays.asList(te).parallelStream()
                .map(x -> x.replace(ISConstants.domainName, ""))
                .filter(x -> (!x.contains("_"))? ArrayUtils.contains(con, x.toLowerCase()): ArrayUtils.contains(con, x.split("_")[0].toLowerCase()))
                .filter(x -> !x.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

//          List<UserDTO> ls = l.forEach;
//          System.out.println(l);

    }
```

Here You can see, I got a list S now I want to convert that list S to List of UserDTO where I have a method `setUserName` and want to set string from S to userName into ls.

Anyone know how can i perform this with Existing lambda expression or with new expression.

Comment: Let me know if more clarification required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other answers show, you could use a constructor that receives a `String` and sets the user name to the DTO.

Or, if you can't add such constructor, here's what you can do:

```
List<UserDTO> result = Arrays.asList(te).stream()
        .map(x -> x.replace(ISConstants.domainName, ""))
        .filter(x -> !x.contains("_") ? 
                     ArrayUtils.contains(con, x.toLowerCase()) : 
                     ArrayUtils.contains(con, x.split("_")[0].toLowerCase()))
        .filter(x -> !x.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
        .map(x -> {
                     UserDTO u = new UserDTO();
                     u.setUserName(x);
                     return u;
         })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here I'm using `Stream.map` to convert the string into a `UserDTO` with that string set as the user name.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for this, But here what about performance? Specifically  for this part .map(x -> {
                     UserDTO u = new UserDTO();
                     u.setUserName(x);
                     return u;
         }

Comment: Hi @Mak, there is no performance penalty, we're creating a DTO per string

Comment: Maybe you can extract the piece of code, use constructor to setUserName in UserDTO, and you change to ``` .map(UserDTO::new)``` for better readability and gives you tiny performance improvements.

Answer (score 4):

By using another `map` operation such as:

```
List<UserDTO> users  = Arrays.asList(te).parallelStream()
        .map(x -> x.replace(ISConstants.domainName, ""))
        .filter(x -> (!x.contains("_"))? ArrayUtils.contains(con, x.toLowerCase()): ArrayUtils.contains(con, x.split("_")[0].toLowerCase()))
        .filter(x -> !x.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
        .map(s -> new UserDTO(s)) // or 'UserDTO::new' by using a constructor with 'name' being set
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(based on [Holger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58831094/java-8-lambda-expression-convert-liststring-to-listdto/58831116?noredirect=1#comment103954547_58831116)) and further improving it with a use of regex such as :

```
List<UserDTO> users = Arrays.asList(te).parallelStream()
        .map(x -> x.replace(ISConstants.domainName, ""))
        .filter(x -> !x.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) // filter in using simpler condition first
        .filter(x -> ArrayUtils.contains(con, x.replaceFirst("_.*", "").toLowerCase())) // simplified using regex
        .map(s -> new UserDTO(s)) // or 'UserDTO::new' by using a constructor with 'name' being set
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: A method reference `.map(UserDTO::new)` can be used here instead of lambda.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz Yes, holds true given the constructor. The intention of the answer was to highlight the approach.

Comment: Still, it might be worth mentioning that `.filter(x -> (!x.contains("_"))? ArrayUtils.contains(con, x.toLowerCase()): ArrayUtils.contains(con, x.split("_")[0].toLowerCase()))` can be replaced by the simpler `.filter(x -> ArrayUtils.contains(con, x.replaceFirst("_.*", "").toLowerCase()))` and that it is beneficial to perform `.filter(x -> !x.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))` before the other filter, as it’s simpler to test and reduces the required number of complex tests.

Comment: Lets suppose .map(s -> new UserDTO(s)) instead of this If I use, .map(x -> {
                     UserDTO u = new UserDTO();
                     u.setUserName(x);
                     return u;
         })
Then there will be impact on performance

Comment: @Mak If you compare both, all you end up doing is creating a new instance of `UserDTO`, so you wouldn't find any performance impact there.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `DTO` has a constructor, that takes one `String`, you can map it:

```
List<DTO> S  = Arrays.asList(te).parallelStream()
            .map(x -> x.replace(ISConstants.domainName, ""))
            .filter(x -> (!x.contains("_"))? ArrayUtils.contains(con, x.toLowerCase()): ArrayUtils.contains(con, x.split("_")[0].toLowerCase()))
            .filter(x -> !x.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
            .map(x -> new DTO(x))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or easier with method reference:

```
List<DTO> S  = Arrays.asList(te).parallelStream()
            .map(x -> x.replace(ISConstants.domainName, ""))
            .filter(x -> (!x.contains("_"))? ArrayUtils.contains(con, x.toLowerCase()): ArrayUtils.contains(con, x.split("_")[0].toLowerCase()))
            .filter(x -> !x.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
            .map(DTO::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```